# python - lottonum duplicate on extractor

Tags: python

```
import random

lotto = []
while True:
    a = random.randint(1, 45)
    lotto.append(a)
    if lotto.count(a) == 2:
        continue
    if len(lotto) == 7:
        break
lotto.sort()
print(lotto)
```

I want to extract numbers of 1 to 45 without duplicates but sometimes two or three of the random numbers overlap. thanks to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create another list that will hold all the numbers you already chosen and will check for duplicates:

```
import random

lotto = []
# List that will hold all chosen numbers so far
dups = []
while True:
    a = random.randint(1, 45)
    # Check for duplicate number
    if a in dups:
        continue
    else:
        #Add it to both dups and lotto
        dups.append(a)
        lotto.append(a)

    if len(lotto) == 7:
        break

lotto.sort()
print(lotto)
```

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose exists [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample):

```
lotto = sorted(random.sample(range(1, 46), 7))
```